# Two real rectangular matrices $AB=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m×n$ real valued matrix and $B$ be an $n×m$ real valued matrix so that $AB$=$I$. Thus we must have

- $n>m$
- $m\ge n$
- if $BA=I$ then $m>n$
- either $BA=I$ or $n>m$

  **What I tried**: Either $n<m$ or $n>m$ → either $\operatorname{Rank}(A) = \operatorname{Rank}(B)=n$ or $n>m$ → either $BA=I_n$ or $n>m$. So option 4 seems to be true to me. But how can I reject option 3?

Comment: If $BA=I$, then $A$ has left and right inverse. The only case a matrix has left and right inverse is that it is a square matrix. This eliminates option $3$.

Comment: ok..thanks Brian Ding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of completeness for the learners in mathematics community, the proof is as follows:

$Rank(AB)=Rank(I_m)=m\implies m\le n$

$\therefore$ either $m<n\ or\ m=n$

In case $m=n$;$AB=I\implies B=A^{-1}\implies BA=I$

Thus, either $m<n\ or\ m=n$ is true.